# Why do tests for POST fail - "duplicate key value violates unique constraint [table name]_pkey"?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, unit-testing, express, knex.js

I'm trucking along with building an API.

**Challenge**

I'm stuck right now with testing two POST endpoints. (1) Ratings and (2) Comments. I'm not sure why new ids aren't created for new comments and ratings. It uses keys that already exist when posting.

When I use Postman, the endpoints function fine.

Here's the repo: [github](https://github.com/peyo/project-cellier-api/tree/master/test). The tests are located within the "test" folder. [table name]-endpoints-spec.js

I've looked into several fixing the sequence entries for Postgresql and that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Thank you in advance!

**Error Log (Ratings)**

> 2020-07-06 21:39:02.970 PDT [19245] ERROR:  duplicate key value
> violates unique constraint "ratings_pkey"
>
> 2020-07-06 21:39:02.970 PDT [19245] DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already
> exists.
>
> 2020-07-06 21:39:02.970 PDT [19245] STATEMENT:  insert into "ratings"
> ("date_created", "rating", "scents_id", "users_id") values ($1, $2,
> $3, $4) returning *
>
> error: insert into "ratings" ("date_created", "rating", "scents_id",
> "users_id") values ($1, $2, $3, $4) returning * - duplicate key value
> violates unique constraint "ratings_pkey"

**Error Log (Comments)**

> 2020-07-06 21:39:01.641 PDT [19234] ERROR:  duplicate key value
> violates unique constraint "comments_pkey"
>
> 2020-07-06 21:39:01.641 PDT [19234] DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already
> exists.
>
> 2020-07-06 21:39:01.641 PDT [19234] STATEMENT:  insert into "comments"
> ("comment", "date_created", "scents_id", "users_id") values ($1, $2,
> $3, $4) returning *
>
> error: insert into "comments" ("comment", "date_created", "scents_id",
> "users_id") values ($1, $2, $3, $4) returning * - duplicate key value
> violates unique constraint "comments_pkey"

Comment: You are passing id:s in test data that are inserted to table, which prevents postgresql autoincrement from kicking in. So next time when you are trying to insert a row without explicitly set id, it will generate id = 1, which is already used and will fail due to unique constraint.

Comment: @Mikael - Thanks for taking the time to answer my question! Very much appreciated. Is it then recommended to create test data without the id numbers?

Comment: @Mikael - A potential solution might be to add the id: into the newComment.

Comment: Yes for the first comment and no to the second. Data should be inserted without id numbers to have sequence updated. Other option is to after inserting initial data update id-sequences manually to highest used id value.

Comment: @peyo Great question, I was dealing with the same problem.